# why is my list getting an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-based

I have my program ask what attack you want and it supposed to get the spells from a list who gets the attacks from `def`'s and I'm getting this error

```
    player_spells = {fire_spells, ice_spells, water_spells, chaos_spells, nature_spells, spirit_spells, equilibrium_spells, intellectual_spells}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

And my code: (Sorry it is so long but i tried to cut it down to the relevant loop and this is as small as i could cut it down)

```
toutorial_dialoug()
enemy_health = 0
player_health = 0
player_max_health = 0

def ember():
    ember = enemy_health - random.randint(95, 125)
def flame():
    flame = enemy_health - random.randint(155, 185)
def inferno():
    inferno = enemy_health - random.randint(250, 285)
def lava_river():
    lava_river = enemy_health - random.randint(300, 400)
def snowflake():
    snowflake = enemy_health - random.randint(75, 100)
def blizard():
    blizard = enemy_health - random.randint(135, 200)
def frostbite():
    frostbite = enemy_health - random.randint(225, 265)
def frozen_lake():
    frozen_lake = enemy_health - random.randint(300, 345)
def tropical_storm():
    tropical_storm = enemy_health - random.randint(125, 145)
def hurricane():
    hurricane = enemy_health - random.randint(200, 255)
def tornado():
    tornado = enemy_health - random.randint(300, 350)
def bubble():
    bubble = enemy_health - random.randint(425, 500)
def raining_cats_and_dogs():
    raining_cats_and_dogs = enemy_health - random.randint(95, 125)
def summon_hades():
    summon_hades = enemy_health - random.randint(155, 185)
def burning_sky():
    burning_sky = enemy_health - random.randint(250, 285)
def swap_pips():
    swap_pips = enemy_health - random.randint(300, 345)
def pans_wraith():
    pans_wraith = enemy_health - random.randint(90, 110)
def bees_knees():
    bees_knees = player_health + 400
def deforestation():
    deforestation = enemy_health - random.randint(200, 255)
def earth_shaker():
    earth_shaker = enemy_health - random.randint(285, 330)
def ghost_touch():
    ghost_touch = enemy_health - 100, player_health + 50
def lost_soul():
    lost_soul = enemy_health - 200, player_health + 100
def death_pixie():
    death_pixie = enemy_health - 300, player_health + 150
def pathogen():
    pathogen = enemy_health - random.randint(412, 445)
def pulse():
    pulse = enemy_health - random.randint(85, 112)
def blind():
    blind = enemy_health - random.randint(185, 215)
def overload():
    overload = enemy_health - random.randint(245, 315)
def equalizer():
    equalizer = enemy_health - random.randint(300, 400)
def acid():
    acid = enemy_health - random.randint(70, 90)
def light_overload():
    light_overload = enemy_health - random.randint(100, 120)
def sound_overload():
    sound_overload = enemy_health - random.randint(200, 220)
def time():
    time = enemy_health - random.randint(300, 330)

fire_spells = {ember(), flame(), inferno(), lava_river()}
ice_spells = {snowflake(), blizard(), frostbite(), frozen_lake()}
water_spells = {tropical_storm(), hurricane(), tornado(), bubble()}
chaos_spells = {raining_cats_and_dogs(), summon_hades(), burning_sky(), swap_pips()}
nature_spells = {pans_wraith(), bees_knees(), deforestation(), earth_shaker()}
spirit_spells = {ghost_touch(), lost_soul(), death_pixie(), pathogen()}
equilibrium_spells = {pulse(), blind(), overload(), equalizer()}
intellectual_spells = {acid(), light_overload(), sound_overload(), time()}
player_spells = {fire_spells, ice_spells, water_spells, chaos_spells, nature_spells, spirit_spells, equilibrium_spells, intellectual_spells}
def choose_school():
    have_school = False
    while False:
        input_str = input()
        if input_str.lower().startswith("I"):
            player_spells = player_spells[2]
            player_max_health = 525
            player_health = 525
            player_level = 1
            have_school = True
        elif input_str.lower().startswith("F"):
            player_spells = player_spells[1]
            player_max_health = 425
            player_health = 425
            player_level = 1
            have_school = True
        elif input_str.lower().startswith("W"):
            player_spells = player_spells[3]
            player_max_health = 400
            player_health = 400
            player_level = 1
            have_school = True
        elif input_str.lower().startswith("C"):
            player_spells = player_spells[4]
            player_max_health = 425
            player_health = 425
            player_level = 1
            have_school = True
        elif input_str.lower().startswith("N"):
            player_spells = player_spells[5]
            player_max_health = 465
            player_health = 465
            player_level = 1
            have_school = True
        elif input_str.lower().startswith("S"):
            player_spells = player_spells[6]
            player_max_health = 450
            player_health = 450
            player_level = 1
            have_school = True
        elif input_str.lower().startswith("E"):
            player_spells = player_spells[7]
            player_max_health = 480
            player_health = 480
            player_level = 1
            have_school = True
        elif input_str.lower().startswith("T"):
            player_spells = player_spells[8]
            player_max_health = 500
            player_health = 500
            player_level = 1
            have_school = True
choose_school()
if player_health > player_max_health:
    while True:
        player_health - 1

if player_spells == ice_spells:
    school_name = 'Ice wizard'
if player_spells == fire_spells:
    school_name = 'Fire wizard'
if player_spells == water_spells:
    school_name = 'Water wizard'
if player_spells == chaos_spells:
    school_name = 'Chaos wizard'
if player_spells == nature_spells:
    school_name = 'Nature wizard'
if player_spells == spirit_spells:
    school_name = 'Spirit wizard'
if player_spells == equilibrium_spells:
    school_name = 'Equilibrium wizard'
if player_spells == intellectual_spells:
    school_name = 'Ice wizard'

print('are you sure you want to be a %s' % (school_name))
input_str = input()
if input_str.lower().startswith("N"):
    choose_school()
```

Comment: because as the error states, you are trying to hash a set by storing it in another set which is not possible

Comment: The `while False` and `while True` statements also make me worry about the final behavior of your program, even if you fix the hashing issue.

Comment: Forgot to fix that it use to be `= False` and `while True` but I tried to fix the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
player_spells = {fire_spells, ice_spells, water_spells, chaos_spells, nature_spells, spirit_spells, equilibrium_spells, intellectual_spells}
```

`player_spells` is a set not a list and somewhere inside one of the elements you are trying to store is also a `set` which is causing your error.

If you want a list, you create it with `[]` not `{}`:

```
  player_spells = [fire_spells, ice_spells, water_spells, chaos_spells, nature_spells, spirit_spells, equilibrium_spells, intellectual_spells]
```

I think tutorials on  [lists](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)  and [if/elif/else](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm) won't hurt.

Use `elifs` instead of all if's:

```
if player_spells == ice_spells:
    school_name = 'Ice wizard'
elif player_spells == fire_spells:
    school_name = 'Fire wizard'
elif player_spells == water_spells:
    school_name = 'Water wizard'
elif player_spells == chaos_spells:
    school_name = 'Chaos wizard'
elif player_spells == nature_spells:
    school_name = 'Nature wizard'
elif player_spells == spirit_spells:
    school_name = 'Spirit wizard'
elif player_spells == equilibrium_spells:
    school_name = 'Equilibrium wizard'
elif player_spells == intellectual_spells:
    school_name = 'Ice wizard'
else:
    school_name = "whatever" # in case none are True you need to set a value for school_name
```

Comment: `print('are you sure you want to be a %s' % (school_name))
NameError: name 'school_name' is not defined`

Comment: That means none of your of statements evaluate to True, add `else:school_name = "foo"` and run it again

Comment: also use `if/elif's` not all ifs

Comment: now there is no errors but it keeps on asking for input over and over

Comment: you should try debugging, I have answered two questions already, if you have more questions I suggest you ask a different question after you have tried to figure out what is wrong yourself first. One big clue is a loop has to break somehow when a certain condition is met or else it will loop forever. You seem to have a poor understanding of the basics, you would be better off learning the basics well before trying to write code.

Comment: You're welcome, I strongly suggest you look at those links I posted, there are tutorials on all the basics on that site

Answer (score 0):

> sets allows you to do operations such as intersection, union,
>   difference, and symmetric difference, i.e operations of math's set
>   theory. Sets doesn't allow indexes are are implemented on hash tables.
>
> lists are are really variable-length arrays, not Lisp-style linked
>   lists. In lists the elements are accessed by indexes. Addition to this
>   padraic also suggested that you are using set not list. So you are
>   getting an error

For more refer the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354515/what-is-the-difference-between-sets-and-lists-in-python) between set and list