# Difference between list and set of integers for time efficiency

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code works time efficiently but if I replace the two lines with comment lines (assigning value to `A` and `B`), it takes much more time to pass certain test cases.
constraints: `n,m in range(10^5)`, any integer in arr is in `range(10^9)`
Please explain.

```
n, m = input().split()
arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
A = set(map(int,input().split()))  #list(map(int,input().split()))
B = set(map(int,input().split()))  #list(map(int,input().split()))
count=0
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] in A:
        count+=1
    elif arr[i] in B:
        count+=-1
print(count)
```

Comment: Testing for membership in a list is `O(n)` where `n` is the length of a list.  Testing for membership in a set is essentially `O(1)`.  In the case of a list, it searches each list element one a a time.  In the case of a set, it's doing a hash lookup.

Comment: first read this thread [list vs set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354515/what-is-the-difference-between-sets-and-lists-in-python) ; secondly why are you using same statement `map(int,input().split())` for thrice? also read about [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) of operations in python.

Answer (score 0):

Look up time in a `list` is O(N) and look up time in `set` is O(1).

To check if an element is contained in a `list` every element of a list has to be checked until either an element is found or not. This gives look up time proportional to size of the list or O(N). `set` is implemented as a hashtable which much more efficient, and look up time is on average O(1), or look up time does not increase much as size of `set` increases.