# What is Difference between the following two?

Tags: python-3.x

a=[12,23,34]
a={12,23,34}
I typed both of them in python 3.5 to see how it was different but couldn't understand it....

Here's my PowerShell

```
   PS C:\Users\CBB\Desktop> python

Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> a={12,12,12}

>>> a
{12}

>>> a={12,23,34}

>>> a
{34, 12, 23}

>>> a=[12,23,45,67]

>>> a
[12, 23, 45, 67]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between sets and lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354515/what-is-the-difference-between-sets-and-lists-in-python)

Comment: Please read a basic tutorial, see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `a=[12,23,34]`, you define a `list` object.

By `a={12,23,34}`, a `set` object is created.

> **Lists** are a part of the core Python language.8 Despite their name,
>   Python’s lists are implemented as dynamic arrays behind the scenes.
>   This means a list allows elements to be added or removed, and the list
>   will automatically adjust the backing store that holds these elements
>   by allocating or releasing memory.
>   Python lists can hold arbitrary elements—“everything” is an object in
>   Python, including functions. Therefore, you can mix and match different kinds of data types and store them all in a single list.
>
> A **set** is an unordered collection of objects that does not allow duplicate elements. Typically, sets are used to quickly test a value for membership in the set, to insert or delete new values from a set, and to
>   compute the union or intersection of two sets.

The above comment borrowed from **Python Tricks** of Dan Bader