# How to compare if a string is in a list and have each item in that list be read in lower()?

Tags: python

I want to see if a new username already exists in a list of users, but for the existing users to also be evaluated user the `lower()` function.

I have already tried this:

```
for nuser in new_users:
        if nuser.lower() not in users.lower():
```

But it does not like the `users.lower()`:

I have also tried changing my `nuser.lower()` to `nuser.title()`, but this is not future proof as I not all users will be writing in `title()` format.

My whole code below:

```
users = ['John', 'Kyle', 'Lily', 'admin', 'Tom']
new_users = ['john', 'Mike', 'TOM', 'Daemon']

if new_users:
    for nuser in new_users:
        if nuser.lower() not in users.lower():
            print("Username: "+nuser+" is available.")
        else:
            print("Username: "+nuser+" is not available, you will have to choose another.")
```

For example I expect TOM and Tom to clash and print that the username is not available.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
users = ['John', 'Kyle', 'Lily', 'admin', 'Tom']
new_users = ['john', 'Mike', 'TOM', 'Daemon']

if new_users:
    users_lower = set(map(str.lower, users))
    for nuser in new_users:
        if nuser.lower() not in users_lower:
            print("Username: "+nuser+" is available.")
        else:
            print("Username: "+nuser+" is not available, you will have to choose another.")
```

`users` is a list it has no attribute `lower` - you must lower the list elements your self and use a set for lookups to be fast (`element in some_list` is much slower than `element in some_set`)

Comment: Why not @Austin?

Comment: Initially you posted the answer without any explanation and then you edited the answer to add explanation.

Comment: What do you mean @ArpitSvt?

Comment: `Initially you posted the answer without any explanation and then you edited the answer to add explanation` So you downvoted for that?

Answer (score 0):

users = ['John', 'Kyle', 'Lily', 'admin', 'Tom']
New_users = ['john', 'Mike', 'TOM', 'Daemon']

Why not lower using list comprehension as follow :

users_lower= [x.lower() for x in users]

And compare New_users lowered to match in that new lowered users list ?

Comment: It's better to use a `set`, as `users_lower` will only be used to test if it contains some item or not. See @Mr_and_Mrs_D's answer.

Comment: Cause he doesn't care about order and duplicates I suppose ?

Comment: As stated in the other answer, it is much faster: `item in some_set` is about O(1), `item in some_list` is O(len(some_list)). And of course, we don't care about order in this case. You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354515/what-is-the-difference-between-sets-and-lists-in-python

Comment: Thank you for the sharing !